# special characters in qlikview

Tags: special-characters, qlikview

I am working with qlikvieww, and i have a problem with the special characters that are generated when we use the function TextBeween(myText).

We have two transformations in the code, in order to get the date from a text:

step1:  Textbetween(MyText,de,à) as result 
step2: Date(result) as MyDate

The step2 is not executed for some Inputs(Texts), cause the variable result is generated with special characters like: ?,â€‹â€‹... (I can see this when i copy the variable result from Qlikview to Notpad++)

I have tried to use the functions: PurgeChar, Replace... but the issue still exsit.

Could you please give me some suggestions about this?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Difficult problem, difficult to help without test data. My first thought might be to try makedate() if you could seperate out the year, month and day with narrower textbetween() or subfield() combinations

Comment: Usually using keepchar() and combination of  Textbetween with Chr() for special char is enough. But as @TheBudac said it is not possible to give solution without example data which makes problem.